# I want to sell a couple if skins on the steam market but my phone authenticator doesnt show anything

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

I am selling the skins on the market. It says "waiting for confirmation", and I have steam guard activated but i still don't see it on my steam app on my phone.

Answer (score 7):

First off, ensure that you're logged in to the same account.

You can do so by going to Account Details and checking if username matches the one on PC:

How to find it on mobile:
[image] [image]

How to find it on client:
[image]

How to find it on web:
[image]

---

Secondly, ensure that you're using Mobile Steam Guard and not Email Steam Guard, which'd email you the sell approval.

[image] [image]

---

Thirdly, if you are sure that you're using Mobile Steam Guard, try pressing the refresh button on top right on confirmations.

[image] [image]